# Bring highligthed points to the front in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, highlight

I am trying to plot a scatterplot for 2 variables of a large timeseries dataset in R, and I would like to highlight the data from one of the months and bring it upfront.
I ahve tried some previous suggested solutions in the forums but they do not seem to work (maybe is because the questions are a bit old and some arguments could be changed with newer versions)
So far I have this:

```
set.seed(123)

date=seq(as.POSIXct("2022-04-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2022-10-31 23:00:00"), by = "hour")
t= abs(rnorm(length(date)))
y= exp(t)+ rnorm(length(date), mean = 0, sd = 3)

df<-data.frame(date=date,t=t,y=y)

df$month<-month(df$date)

highlight_month <- 1 
non_highlighted_colors <- rep("grey", length(unique(df$month)))
non_highlighted_colors[highlight_month] <- "red"
df$order<-ifelse(df$month==highlight_month,1,2)

ggplot(df, aes(t, y)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(month),order=order)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = non_highlighted_colors) +
  labs(color = "Month") +
  theme_minimal()
```

The first thing I get is that order has been ignored. I think maybe it is because I notice that if I highlightmonth 1 in the code that means month 4 in the dataframe, and when I run order it will search for january, which is not in the data.

Is this the reason the code is not working.

Thank you for any suggestion

Comment: I’m not sure , but would suggest you try running the code in a fresh session where instead of creating a bunch of free names vectors and then bundling into a dataframe, that you instead create them within a call to `data.frame`. That way you may get error messages that point to errors in the specification of arguments to `ggplot`. In the current situation there are two copies of “date”, “t”, and “y” and we can’t be sure whether the interpreter is getting one or the other. (Done correctly it’s also less typing. )

Comment: There is plenty of way to do that, I think. My favorite way would be to plot all the data first with a `scale_color_manual` (in order to have nice legend) and add an other `geom_point()` layer with a specific color.
However, I think you were close, you made some little mistakes: 1) You don't have dates in January (first month),  `df$order<-ifelse(df$month==highlight_month,1,2)` shoud be something like `df$order<-ifelse(df$month==4,1,2)`    (using a logic of the first month starting in april is confusing) 
2)  use `df %>% arrange(desc(order))` as the `data` of your `ggplot`

Comment: See [this example](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/faq-reordering.html?q=order#overplotting) from  ggplot's documentation. You need two split the plotting into two `geom_point`s, to make sure one gets drawn on top of the other.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. This is a dummy dataset created to illustrate my problem (sorry if it was confusing but it was the only way I knew how to create a date column per hour). The other lines are just me trying to highlight the month and try to then pull the vectors into the ggplot but it was not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make thinks simpler by mapping the colour to a condition, and by specifying a manual colour scale:

```
ggplot(df, aes(t, y)) +
geom_point(aes(colour = month == 4)) +
scale_colour_manual(values = c("grey", "red")) +
labs(colour = "Month") +
theme_minimal()
```

[image: plot1]

But you probably want to bring the highlighted points to the front, so you'll need to split the plotting into two `geom_point`s to make sure that the highlighted points get drawn after (i.e. on top) of the grey ones:

```
ggplot(df, aes(t, y)) +
  geom_point(data = df[df$month != 4, ], aes(colour = month == 4)) +
  geom_point(data = df[df$month == 4, ], aes(colour = month == 4)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("grey", "red")) +
  labs(colour = "Month") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: plot2]

You probably want a nicer legend, so you can do something like construct a `factor` variable with the highlighting condition and map that to color:

```
df$highlight <- factor(df$month == 4,
                       levels = c(T, F),
                       labels = c("April", "Other"))

ggplot(df, aes(t, y)) +
  geom_point(data = df[df$highlight == "Other", ], aes(colour = highlight)) +
  geom_point(data = df[df$highlight == "April", ], aes(colour = highlight)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("grey", "red")) +
  labs(colour = "Month") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: plot3]

But since the order of the legend is the plotting order, `Other` comes first in the legend, and it looks weird.  It can be corrected by specifying both the breaks and the values for the colour scale:

```
ggplot(df, aes(t, y)) +
  geom_point(data = df[df$highlight == "Other", ], aes(colour = highlight)) +
  geom_point(data = df[df$highlight == "April", ], aes(colour = highlight)) +
  scale_colour_manual(breaks = c("April", "Other"),
                      values = c("red", "grey")) +
  labs(colour = "Month") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]